# String.Format como funcionalidad en T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, string, transact-sql

Estoy buscando una función incorporada / función extendida en T-SQL para la manipulación de cadenas similar al método String.Format en .NET.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Tu pregunta es de muy mala calidad para la red y debería ser mejorada para que no termine cerrada (todo y que sea una pregunta autorespondida), debes seguir las pautas que se exponen en [ask] para saber realizar una buena pregunta en el sitio. Te animo tambien a que hagas el [tour] y así obtendrás tu primera medalla :)

Comment: Podrías lograr una funcionalidad similar usando REPLACE anidados.

Answer (score 3):

Si estas usando SQL Server 2012 o superior , se puede usar FORMATMESSAGE. ej.

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(50) = 'Mundo';
DECLARE @d INT = 123;
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('Hola %s, %d', @s, @d)

-- RETURNS 'Hola Mundo, 123'
```